# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'batch:job'

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am getting this error in the applicationContext.xml for batch processing
applicationContext as below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<beans xmlns:batch='http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch'
    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' 
    xmlns:context='http://www.springframework.org/schema/context'
    xmlns:tx='http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx' 
    xmlns='http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans'
    xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/spring-batch.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd'>

    <import resource="datasource-tx-jpa.xml" />

    <!-- we can use annotations -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- package to look for annotated classes -->
    <context:component-scan base-package='com.anirban.batch' />

    <!-- we will manage transactions with annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="databaseType" value="oracle" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="ISOLATION_DEFAULT" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobLauncher"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>

    <!-- XML Marshaller -->
    <bean id="matchMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller">
        <property name="mappingLocation" value="oxm-mapping.xml" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Batch job: Contact import -->
    <batch:job id="importContactJob">
        <batch:step id="readWriteStep">
            <batch:tasklet transactionManager="transactionManager">
                <batch:chunk reader="contactItemReader" processor="contactItemProcessor"
                    writer="contactItemWriter" commit-interval="4" />
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
        <batch:listners>
            <batch:listner ref="importContactJoblistener" />
        </batch:listners>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="contactItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
        <property name="resource" value="file:///#{jobParameters['contact.xml']" />
        <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="person" />
        <property name="unMarshaller" ref="batchMarshaller" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="contactItemWriter"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.adapter.ItemWriterAdapter">
        <property name="targetObject" value="PersonDao" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="save" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="personDao" class="com.anirban.batch.dao.impl.PersonDaoImpl" />
    <!-- <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/> </bean> -->

    <bean id="log4jInitialization"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>log4j.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I am getting the below marker error for

Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Start tag of element 
    - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 
    'batch:job'.

When I am trying to run, it is throwing below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 46 in XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 46; columnNumber: 35; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'batch:job'.
```

and

```
Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/spring-batch.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

POM Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-batch.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-batch.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Batch Jars available in Maven Dependencies
1. spring-batch-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar
2. spring-batch-infrastructure-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar

Can someone please help?

Comment: This is typically a classpath issue.  Are you sure that you have the batch jars on your classpath?

Comment: Yes. Below dependencies added for batch

    <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
   <version>${spring-batch.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
   <version>${spring-batch.version}</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: When providing more information, please edit your question..don't use comments.  Also, that's just your POM's dependencies.  I'm asking if the jars are actually there.  How are you packaging/running your app?

Comment: @MichaelMinella Yes. jars are available in the maven dependencies. I am using STS. Trying to run directly from STS through a main method.

Comment: Try with latest spring  version. "3.0.1.RELEASE" or later version..